# IOException: stream is closed, NullPointerException with HttpURLConnection disconnect

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, connection, httpurlconnection, inputstreamreader

everyone. I'm coding a function that connects to a server by using Class HttpURLConnection. In the code, I establish a connection, call getOutputStream() and getInputStream() methods in order. Then I disconnect the connection. After this, I try to get data which has been obtained by getInputStream() method, but the compiler reminds NullPointerException.

Code in below:

```
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    InputStreamReader inStrReader = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {
        URL postUrl = new URL(null, url, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) postUrl.openConnection();
        ...//some setting methods
        connection.connect();
        out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(JSONObject.toJSONString(param));
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        inStrReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
        reader = new BufferedReader(inStrReader);
        connection.disconnect();   //<--HERE, release the connection
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {     //<--null pointer
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (inStrReader != null) {
            try {
                inStrReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

After debug attempts, When I move the disconnection line to the last line in finally module, everything will be ok. But I'm confused, which happens when I already assgined the 'inputstream' value to 'reader'.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning isn't equal to reading, `reader.readLine()` start read from connection.

[InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) is using the connection to read bytes, you disconnect before it read the bytes using the connection

> An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character
>   streams: It reads bytes and ...

Comment: Before disconnect, I already get the the inputstream object into variable 'reader'. However, When I debug, reader.readLine() method gets the nullpointexception.

Comment: But you didn't read anything, in order to read the connection should be open because you are reading using it

Answer (score 0):

Remember it is an "stream". You need to have an active connection to read from stream. Close the connection only after you have retrieved your data from stream.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for the explicit explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything in the wrong order. It doesn't make sense.

1. You're disconnecting and then expecting to be able to read from the connection. Total nonsense here. Normally you shouldn't disconnect at all, as you interfere with HTTP connection pooling. Just remove it, or, if you must have it, do it after all the closes.
2. You're closing in the wrong order, but you don't need to close `inStrReader` at all. Closing the `BufferedReader` does that. Just remove all the code for `inStrReader.close()`.
3. You're closing `out` twice. Don't do that.
4. `connect()` happens implicitly. You don't need to call it yourself.
5. `new URL(url)` is sufficient. You haven't needed to provide the HTTPS `Handler` since about 2003.

Comment: Thx for your suggestions. I maintain this code just because of the HP fortify(HP Enterprise Security Products). If I remove the close() methods in  finally module, then I will receive some warnings with unreleased resources: stream.

Comment: Then don't declare the `InputStreamReader` as a variable. Just do `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))`.

Comment: that's the initial code, fortify reports unreleased resources: stream. Then I declare the InputStreamReader as a variable.

Comment: So close it, it doesn't matter, but not before the `BufferedReader`. Use try-with-resources to make this all cleaner.